# How to make an UI as it is in the screenshot?

Tags: iphone, image, photo, imessage

I am working on an **iPhone** application. I have an option to select existing photos from **Album**. There should be an option for quick access for some images as it is in **iMessage**. Please check the attached screenshot for more information.

Any idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question:

First I am reading maximum 20 recent images from Photo Album using below `code`. Then I am adding all the images into `UIScrollView`. The last one is `More`. If user click on it, it will show iPhone default `"UIImagePickerController"` to choose other images.

#### *If anybody found a better solution, please post it.*

#### Code

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
        if (asset) {
            if ([self.stackForImages count] >= 20) {
                // Stop the enumerations
                *stop = YES;
                *innerStop = YES;
                [self initializeMedia];
            } else {
                ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [workingDictionary setObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] forKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
                [workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]] forKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
                [workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]] forKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                [workingDictionary setObject:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
                [self.stackForImages addObject:workingDictionary];
            }
        }
    }];
    if ([self.stackForImages count] > 0) {
        [self initializeMedia];
    }
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
}];
```